# do I need to commit manually when perform operations in Oracle Sql Developer

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I deleted several rows in a table in Oracle Sql Developer. Then I called a GET API to return all the rows in the table, and I found the deleted rows are returned too. After I restarted the Sql developer, I found the deleted rows appears in the table again in Sql developer too. Looks the delete transaction was not committed. I think each transaction in sql developer is commited automatically. Do I need to commit manually in Sql developer after perform a delete operation?

Comment: Look in the SQL Developer preferences - there is an autocommit option, which if off by default.

Comment: In my opinion, autocommit is *evil*. I'd rather be late than sorry, i.e. manually commit once I'm sure that I deleted what I wanted, than cry over rows I can't restore any more. OK, true, there are options (use backup, see if flashback is enabled) but - why?

Comment: @AlexPoole Thanks! you are right, the auto commit is off. I committed manually instead and the problem is solved.